# installing android command line tools using sdkmanager on windows

Tags: android, cmd, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I am trying to install android command line tools using sdkmanager on windows for hybrid android app development in SAP web IDE. Also I am under a proxy network and when I try to set proxy using cmd by the command :

```
sdkmanager --list --verbose --no_https --proxy=http --proxy_host=10.60.11.11 --proxy_port=8080
```

It displays the error :

```
Info: Parsing C:\Users\10002001\Downloads\sdk-tools-windows-
3859397\tools\package.xml
Info: Parsing C:\Users\10002001\Downloads\sdk-tools-windows-
3859397\tools\package.xml
Info: Failed to validate the XML for the repository at URL 
'http://dl.google.com
/android/repository/repository2-1.xml/repository-12.xml'
 Warning: Errors during XML parse:
Warning: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
- with linked exception:
[java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
Warning: Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.
Warning: Failed to parse source list at 
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml
Warning: File C:\Users\10002001\.android\repositories.cfg could not be 
loaded.
Installed packages:
 --------------------------------------
tools
Description:        Android SDK Tools 26.0.1
Version:            26.0.1
Installed Location: C:\Users\10002001\Downloads\sdk-tools-windows-3859397\to
ols

done
```

And when I give this command to install platform tools :

```
sdkmanager platform-tools
```

It gives this result:

```
   Warning: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
   Warning: File C:\Users\10002001\.android\repositories.cfg could not be 
   loaded.
   Warning: Failed to download any source lists!
   Warning: Failed to find package platform-tools
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

With sdkmanager you should always use proxy switches. I did not yet found a way to make it a system or user setting.

`sdkmanager platform-tools --no_https --proxy=http --proxy_host=10.60.11.11 --proxy_port=8080`

For file warning simply create an empty file at `C:\Users\10002001\.android\repositories.cfg`

For connection exception make sure the user has internet access and try opening the link `https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml` in a browser or wget/curl.