# How to run sdkmanager behind a proxy?

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-manager

At my workplace, we have a corporate proxy that signs every incoming connections and we need to authenticate to be able to connect to Internet. I've configured the proxy in way too many places, and I got most software to use it. Now, the only program left (for now) that disrespect my config is `sdkmanager`. So, how do I make `sdkmanager` respect my proxy/authentication/certificate config?

```
sdkmanager 
Warning: File /home/users/n.gendron/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
Warning: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out) 
Warning: Failed to download any source lists!                                   
[=======================================] 100% Computing updates...
```

- `Android Studio / Appearance & Behaviour / System Settings / HTTP Proxy` is correctly configured, and `Check connection` says `Connection successful`.
- `Android Studio / Appearance & Behaviour / System Settings / Android SDK` does fetch updates without errors. I can even install new Android SDK Platforms.
- `Android Studio / Tools / Server Certificates` has the correct certificate imported
- `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` and `no_proxy` are correctly configured in my `.profile`.
- Certificate is added to multiple keystores with `sudo /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/keytool -importcert -file /etc/ssl/certs/guardianCA.pem -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/security/cacerts`.
- `~/.android/androidtool.cfg` has yet another copypasta of my settings

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's too late for a reply, I was going through the same problem. So answering now so that others can get help from it.

Basically SDK manager proxy hasn't been set so using command line proxy tunneling is helpful in this case.

This post has been helpful for me [installing android command line tools using sdkmanager on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46293077/installing-android-command-line-tools-using-sdkmanager-on-windows).

If all the path variables are set properly

```
"%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin\sdkmanager" "emulator" "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28" "build-tools;28.0.3" "extras;android;m2repository" "extras;google;m2repository" --no_https --proxy=http --proxy_host=10.60.11.11 --proxy_port=8080
```

or

you can navigate to the directory where sdkmanager.bat file is set it in the path variable, or run this command directly from that location

```
sdkmanager "emulator" "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28" "build-tools;28.0.3" "extras;android;m2repository" "extras;google;m2repository" --no_https --proxy=http --proxy_host=10.60.11.11 --proxy_port=8080
```